# std::bad_alloc exception although there is enough free memory

Tags: c++, bad-alloc

my code runs under 64bit Linux (openSUSE 13.1 x86_64), the compiler is gcc (SUSE Linux) 4.8.1. I get at some point of the execution of my program a std::bad_alloc exception, which stems from a std::vector push_back call. As seen in gdb:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff6053849 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff6054cd8 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff694c655 in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff694a7c6 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff694a7f3 in std::terminate() () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00007ffff694aa1e in __cxa_throw () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00007ffff694af1d in operator new(unsigned long) () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0x0000000000457ca6 in allocate (__n=8388608, this=0x7ffffffe1f80)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.8/ext/new_allocator.h:104
#8  _M_allocate (__n=8388608, this=0x7ffffffe1f80) at /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:168
#9  std::vector<std::pair<long, long>, std::allocator<std::pair<long, long> > >::_M_insert_aux (
    this=this@entry=0x7ffffffe1f80, __position=..., __x=...) at /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/vector.tcc:345
#10 0x000000000045335c in push_back (__x=..., this=0x7ffffffe1f80) at /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:913
#11 c_RoutingNetzwerk::LoescheAktuelleKnoten (this=this@entry=0x7ffffffe2f30,
    aktuelle_knoten=std::vector of length 12803276, capacity 16777216 = {...}, ebene=ebene@entry=0,
    aktueller_kantengrad=std::vector of length 17266677, capacity 17266677 = {...}, algo=...,
    neue_abgehende_kanten=std::vector of length 4194304, capacity 4194304 = {...},
    neue_eingehende_kanten=std::vector of length 4194304, capacity 4194304 = {...})
    at RoutingAlgorithmus/RoutingNetzwerk.cpp:3275
```

A call to neue_abgehende_kanten.push_back(...) doubles the size of the vector, so I am trying to allocate 4194304 * 2 * 16 Bytes = 128 MBytes, and this fails.

On the other hand I have more than enough memory (132 GBytes all in all), and enough memory is free (snapshot taken while my program is interrupted in the debugger):

```
m2883:~ # free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        129151     128582        568          0         59      56334
-/+ buffers/cache:      72189      56962
Swap:         8195          5       8190
```

Any ideas why the allocation fails nonetheless ? It looks to me as if the system doesn't free its caches for use by my program ?!

---

I just tried a little experiment, and came up with

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char** argv)
{
    void* p = calloc( 1, 256 * 1024 * 1024 );
    if ( !p )
        printf( "failed\n" );
    else
        printf( "all done\n" );
}
```

This still works for 128 MByte, but fails for 256 MByte.

And:

```
m2883:~ # free -mh
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          126G       125G       593M         0B        60M        54G
-/+ buffers/cache:        70G        55G
Swap:         8.0G       5.4M       8.0G

transit@m2883:~/test> ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 1033140
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1033140
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

---

It seems that the server is misconfigured in some way. Even on a freshly booted system with nothing running than a few system services I can't allocate more than about 70 GBytes, which I read as 64 GBytes + 8 GBytes swap space. I have contacted the server hoster, and complained about the situation.

Comment: Possibly there's a per-process limit of memory available in your system?

Comment: Could you use `free -mh` instead ? The units are unclear. Your heap could be corrupted.

Comment: It isn't just the amount of free memory.  It is the amount of *contiguous* memory that is required.

Comment: Test program works for me just fine, 16GB system with Ubuntu 14.10. Look at your system config, not C++.

Comment: I have to add that there are two other programs running concurrently which use up nearly 70G. I have no doubt that killing them will enable me to allocate 256M

Comment: Got the same Issues, any solution what was wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Without information about your code and system configuration, it's hard to know for sure.

Memory fragmentation would explain the symptom.   The memory used by a vector is contiguous and, even if the total memory available is sufficient, the allocation will fail if there is no single contiguous block of the required size available to be allocated.

Repeated allocation, deallocation, and reallocation can easily result in memory fragmentation.

Exceeding some quota would also explain the behaviour.

Comment: The memory used by the caches can't be fragmented, can it ?!

Comment: Any memory can become fragmented.  Fragmentation is a result of usage (e.g. patterns of allocation and release).